# Rambam held of Timtum halev?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, hashkafah-philosophy, rambam, story-identification

[There](http://parsha.blogspot.com/2012/04/rambam-on-timtum-halev.html) is a famous story of the Rambam in the name of R' Chaim Brisker:

> "When the Rambam visited Yemen, he met a certain gaon of the geonim of the time. And after the Rambam returned home, this gaon would regularly write him questions and answers. One time, a letter reached him from the gaon, and on the page was a deep question in philosophy. The Rambam was much astounded at this question, and he said, 'I don't understand how this is so, that a question like this could arise in the mind of a Jew... for questions such as this do not arise in the Jewish mind until his soul is an impure soul. And the Rambam refrained from answering him regarding his question.
>
> After some length of time, this fellow continued sending many letters, until the Rambam felt that he had to answer him. And his answer to the gaon was: Go and check the slaughterers and the inspectors in your community.
>
> Upon receipt of the letter, the gaon followed the instructions of the Rambam. And then was revealed that for thirteen years, they had fed him and the entire city neveilos and tereifos, such that even a gaon such as himself came up with a question of minus and apikorsus."

What is the source of this story?

1. Is it in any of R' Chaim's published works?
2. Is it found in any Rishonim?

Comment: sounds like bubuh maisas. RaMbaM didn't believe in superstitions as these.

Comment: Also, the yeshivot of Sura and Pumbedita had been destroyed; there were no geonim in the 12th century.

Comment: @ShimonbM Gaonim could be in colloquial, not technical.

Comment: the blog refers to the source. the story sounds like a joke though, i think i can count 17 problems with it.

Comment: For one thing, the Rambam never visited Yemen.

Comment: The Rambam would say such a thing? Hard to believe (as was already pointed out.)

Comment: Could be from Igros Teiman

Comment: Rabbeinu Bachaya talks about timtum halev

Answer (score 3):

It seems there is a letter of the Rambam that is the source of this

מובא בשו"ת דברי יציב (חלק יו"ד סימן ב) (כ"ק האדמו"ר מצאנז קלויזנבורג זצ"ל)   ‏

> "**ובאגרת הרמב"ם** [מובא בצפנת פענח פרשת יתרו דף ס"ד ע"א] שכל מה שבאו לידי הרהורי  כפירה ר"ל הכל מכח שאכלו נבילות וטריפות ונטמטמו עיי"ש באריכות.‏
>   ובדברי חיים ח"א סי' ז', ודבר זה ידוע שאין דבר עבירה כמאכלות אסורות שמטמטם הלב הישראל, ובעוה"ר עי"ז יצאו כמעט מן הדת כמה קהלות בארץ לועז ע"י השו"ב הקלים ואכלו ונתפטמו בטריפות, וגברו  עליהם דיעות זרות עד שפקרו ונאבדו מתוך קהל הקדוש עכל"ק, ותסמר שערות ראש ממה  שהאריכו עוד בספה"ק מחומר הענין, ואשר על כן צריך לדקדק ביותר בענין חמור כזה ולא  סמכינן על השוחט בחזקת כשרות גרידא, ומה גם שהוא שוחט בקביעות וגם לרבים שחשו  חכז"ל ביותר וכנ"ל".‏

The story is probably not in another rishoin but the sources on the subject can be found [here](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/2219)

Comment: Does anyone have more info about this letter? It's obviously probably not originally Rambam's, but where did it come from?

Comment: @DoubleAA it seems he was looking for any printed Source , I think my answer helps (I am trying to find the צפנת פענח , their are a lot of books printed with that name, (I am still looking)

Answer (score 1):

The source seems to be the Ba'al Shem Tov, cited by his grandson [R. Moshe Chaim Ephraim of Sudilkov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Chaim_Ephraim_of_Sudilkov), in his *Degel Machaneh Ephraim*, *Parashas Ekev*, in the name of [R. Yaakov Yosef of Polnoye](http://www.yivoencyclopedia.org/article.aspx/Yaakov_Yosef_of_Polnoye). Here is the quote from the Degel Machaneh Ephraim:

> אחר כותבי זאת מצאתי בכתבי קודש של מוה"ר יעקב יוסף הכהן נר"י, וזה לשונו
>   והענין ששמעתי ממורי בשם שו"ת כתבי הרמב"ם ז"ל ששאלו איך מרומזת תחיית
>   המתים בתורה ואי מכח הוכחת חז"ל הלא יש להוכיח וכו', והשיב הרמב"ם אני
>   אבאר לכם סיבת הוויתכם מאין נמשך לכם ספק זה כי אותם שהם בני אברהם יצחק
>   ויעקב וכו' והנה יש שמים וארץ ושבעה כוכבי לכת ובדמותן יש בני אדם וכו'
>   ויש לשאול מאי טעמא לא רצתה הארץ להיות בחינת שמים וצריך לומר שלא ניתן
>   זה הדעת להארץ להתאוה להיות בחינת שמים וזה שאמרו (ראש השנה י"א א)
>   לצביונם נבראו לדעתם נבראו וכן לענין בני אדם שיש צורך לעולם להיות שלש
>   כתות ניתן לזה דעת שיתאוה להיות בחינת שמים וזה לבחינת הארץ וכו' וכי
>   תימא אם כן תקשה בחירה וידיעה וכו' ויצירת אדם ומאכלו האוכל נתברר במעיו
>   על ידי המרה הזורקת טיפה נברר הגס לצואה בחינת שניה למי רגלים שלישית
>   לזיעה רביעית ציפרנים ושער חמישית נבלע בכבד וטחול וכו' ומשם נברר הטוב
>   והצלול ונכנס ללב ומוח ומזה נעשה השכל ומדבריכם שאתם כופרים בדברי חז"ל
>   לא נזהרתם ממאכלי איסור אם כן נעשה השכל שלכם מדברים טמאים וטריפות והשכל
>   נמשך להכריע אל הטומאות והטריפות שנעשה השכל ממנו אם כן איך תוכלו להכריע
>   בשכל שלכם וכו' ואתם משורש סדום ועמורה והסוף שלכם וכו' ודברי פי חכם חן

This is also cited in the name of R. Chaim of Brisk in the *Sefer Chaim Be'Emunasam*, by R. Reuven Schmeltzer, p. 58, citing *Toras Chaim*, end of *Parashas Shemini*. It would seem that this is the source for the story cited here:

> עי' בס' תורת חיים ס"פ שמיני מכת"י של המגיד מריטובה הג"ר יששכר בער ששמע
>   מהגר"ח ז"ל שגאון אחד מגאוני הזמן היה מתכתב עם הרמב"ם בתדירות ופעם שאל
>   קושיא בפילוסופיה ונתפלא הרמב"ם עליה ואמר קושיות כאלה אינן עולות על דעת
>   העברי אא"כ נפשם הוא נפש טמאה, ונמע מלהשיבו, אך האיש המשיך לשגר עוד
>   מכתבים עד אשר הרמב"ם השיבו, "צא ובדוק את השוחטים ובודקים בקהילתך",
>   וגילו שזה י"ג שנה האכילו נבילות וטריפות [ויעו"ש עוד נוסח קצת שונה בשם
>   הגר"ח].

Comment: They are clearly referencing a pre-existing forgery, so saying that the besht is *the* source isn't the most accurate.  This does however show that the forgery dates back to at least the18th century.

Comment: @mevaqesh the earliest source that we have, or in short, the source

Comment: how do you know it is he earliest source available?

Comment: @mevaqesh because it doesn't seem to be quoted in any earlier sources.